# Image from Url in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to set an image from a web service for which I am using:

```
private class FetchImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(arg0[0]).getContent());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

And trying to fetch it like

```
final ImageView imgicon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgicon); 
    new FetchImageTask() {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

            if (result != null) {
                imgicon.setImageBitmap(result);

            }
        }
    }.execute("Url/images/"+bitmapname);
```

But it doesn't display it nor any error. Any guess?

Answer (score 1):

### From Android-developers blog

Use this Async Task

```
class BitmapDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
private String url;
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

public BitmapDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

@Override
// Actual download method, run in the task thread
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
     // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
     return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
}

@Override
// Once the image is downloaded, associates it to the imageView
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = null;
    }

    if (imageViewReference != null) {
        ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Use this function for download bitmap from url

```
static Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
final AndroidHttpClient client = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("Android");
final HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);
    final int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error " + statusCode + " while retrieving bitmap from " + url); 
        return null;
    }

    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = entity.getContent(); 
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return bitmap;
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();  
            }
            entity.consumeContent();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Could provide a more explicit error message for IOException or IllegalStateException
    getRequest.abort();
    Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error while retrieving bitmap from " + url, e.toString());
} finally {
    if (client != null) {
        client.close();
    }
}
return null;
}
```

Call asynctask as follows

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(yourImageViewId);
BitmapDownloaderTask mDownloaderTask = new BitmapDownloaderTask(mImageView);
mDownloaderTask.execute("YourDownloadUrlHere");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
private class FetchImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        Bitmap b = null;
        try {
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(arg0[0]).getContent());
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

        if (result != null) {
            imgicon.setImageBitmap(result);

        }
    }
}
```

then call it like this:

```
final ImageView imgicon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgicon); 
new FetchImageTask().execute("Url/images/"+bitmapname);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Download the `AndroidQuery` jar](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/detail?name=android-query-full.0.25.10.jar).
2. Put this jar into your `libs` folder and right-click on jar and *Build Path -> Add to build path*

Use it based on this sample:

```
AQuery androidQuery = new AQuery(this); // make AndroidQuery object

androidQuery
    .id(yourImageView)
    .image(
        imageUrl,
        isCacheUrlImageOnMemery, 
        isCacheUrlImageOnFile);
```

If true then given URL image cache on memory so after word android query check is given URL image cache on either memory or file then it take from cache other wise it try to getting from URL

```
isCacheUrlImageOnMemery
```

Same like `isCacheUrlImageOnMemery` but first of all android query check on memory then file in case if we have not much of memory then we cache on file the two option are available.

```
isCacheUrlImageOnFile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private class FetchImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(arg0[0]);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {


            imageview.setImageBitmap(mybitmap);

        }
    }
```