# Load images with universal image loader and Aquery from database

Tags: android, mysql, android-listview, android-imageview

Hey guys i am building an app that loads data from mysql and it populates a listview. i have in every row an imageview which i want to populate with images from db..actually its the path of an image. i used universal image loader and android aquery and none of it works or its something i do wrong.

My code is:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean network_connected = activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isAvailable()
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (!network_connected) {
            onDetectNetworkState().show();
        } else {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                accessWebService();
                registerCallClickBack();
            }
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                String skipMessage = settings.getString("skipMessage",
                        "NOT checked");
                if (!skipMessage.equals("checked")) {
                    onAlertMobileData().show();

                }
                if (skipMessage.equals("checked")) {
                    accessWebService();
                    registerCallClickBack();
                }
            }
        }

        ImageLoader imageLoader=new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());


        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(MainActivity.this).build();
        ImageLoader.getInstance();

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher_stock_custom_icon)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher_stock_custom_icon)
        .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        .considerExifParams(true)
        .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300))
        .build();

    }
```

and where i get the images from db is here:

```
public void ListDrawer() {
        stocksList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        try {
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("metoxes");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");
                String price = jsonChildNode.optString("price");
                String price1 = jsonChildNode.optString("price1");
                String price2 = jsonChildNode.optString("price2");
                String price3 = jsonChildNode.optString("price3");
                String price4 = jsonChildNode.optString("price4");
                String price5 = jsonChildNode.optString("price5");
                String price6 = jsonChildNode.optString("price6");
                String price7 = jsonChildNode.optString("price7");
                String price8 = jsonChildNode.optString("price8");
                String price9 = jsonChildNode.optString("price9");
                String price10 = jsonChildNode.optString("price10");
                String price11 = jsonChildNode.optString("price11");
                String price12 = jsonChildNode.optString("price12");
                String price13 = jsonChildNode.optString("price13");
                String price14 = jsonChildNode.optString("price14");
                String price15 = jsonChildNode.optString("price15");
                imageUri = jsonChildNode.optString("image");
                image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagestartinglist);
                loader.displayImage(imageUri, image, options);

                stocksList.add(createStockList(name, price, price1, price2,
                        price3, price4, price5, price6, price7, price8, price9,
                        price10, price11, price12, price13, price14, price15));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    RefreshActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent1, 0);
        }
        /*AQuery aq = new AQuery(MainActivity.this);
        boolean memCache = true;
        boolean fileCache = true;
        aq.id(R.id.imagestartinglist).image(imageUri, memCache, fileCache);*/
        //imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageUri, image);
        String[] from = { "name", "price" };
        int[] to = { R.id.stock_name, R.id.stock_price };
        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, stocksList,
                R.layout.list_item, from, to);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);

    }
```

can anybody help me?? i have added both libraries to build path and also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

those permisions are on my manifest.. what am i missing??

Comment: did u get the json data correct?

Comment: http://stockpredictions.url.ph/getstocks.php this is my json data file

Comment: look at my ans for how to use "AndroidQuery" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651291/image-from-url-in-android/19651443#19651443

Comment: I have never use Aquery but use universal image loader one of my project

Comment: i will try this and i let you know

Comment: but my opinoun firts create a arraylist like this   stocksList = new ArrayList<Stok>();,later fill this

Comment: well with your answer on that post it doesnt load the images only loads the one i predifined to load...

Comment: it doesnt load the images either with aquery or universal image loader.