# Load image from URL into gridview

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gridview, imageview

i have a problem for load image from url to gridview

load image url from imageview already success
but, load image url from gridview doesn't work

[ScreenShoot](http://cdn.kaskus.com/images/2014/07/07/1893408_20140707115646.png)

HalamanUtama.Java

```
import android.content.Intent;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

import android.widget.AdapterView;

import android.widget.GridView;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.TextView;



/**

 * A simple {@link android.support.v4.app.Fragment} subclass.

 * 

 */

public class HalamanUtama extends android.app.Fragment {



 public HalamanUtama() {

  // Required empty public constructor

 }



 @Override

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,

   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  // Inflate the layout for this fragment



        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_halaman_utama, container,

    false);



        try{

         int loader = R.drawable.loader;

        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.banner);

        String image_url = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png";

        ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);



        } catch (Exception e){}



        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view1);

        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));



        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override

         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,

           long arg3) {

          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity

                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), FullImage.class);

                // passing array index

                i.putExtra("id", arg2);

                startActivity(i);

         }

  });



        return view;

 }



}
```

ImageAdapter.Java

```
import java.io.InputStream;

import java.net.URL;



import android.R.drawable;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import android.widget.GridView;

import android.widget.ImageView;

import android.widget.TextView;



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Context mContext;

 private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;



 // Keep all Images in array

    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {

            R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,

            R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4,

            R.drawable.pic5, R.drawable.pic6,

            R.drawable.pic7

    };



    public String[] titleProduct={

      "satu", "dua", "tiga",

      "empat","lima","enam",

      "tujuh"

    };



 // Constructor

    public ImageAdapter(Context c){

        mContext = c;

     mLayoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(c);

    }



    @Override

    public int getCount() {

        return mThumbIds.length;

    }



    @Override

    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return mThumbIds[position];

    }



    @Override

    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return 0;

    }



    @Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       /*ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

         imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

         imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

         imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));*/

       //return imageView;



     ViewHolder mVHolder;



     if(convertView==null){

      convertView=mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_grid, parent, false);

      mVHolder=new ViewHolder();

      mVHolder.mImageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageProduct);

            mVHolder.mTextView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleProduct);

            mVHolder.mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

            mVHolder.mImageView.setPadding(8,8,8,8);

            convertView.setTag(mVHolder);

     } else{

      mVHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

     }



     try{

     ImageLoader imgLoader=new ImageLoader(mContext);

     imgLoader.DisplayImage("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png", R.drawable.loader, mVHolder.mImageView);



        mVHolder.mTextView.setText(titleProduct[position]);

     } catch (Exception e){}

        return convertView;

    }



    static class ViewHolder{

     ImageView mImageView;

     TextView mTextView;

    }





}
```

Logcat

```
 07-07 12:05:41.419: D/AbsListView(26215): Get MotionRecognitionManager
    07-07 12:05:41.449: D/AbsListView(26215): Get MotionRecognitionManager
    07-07 12:05:41.479: D/dalvikvm(26215): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 166K, 10% free 9404K/10375K, paused 23ms, total 24ms
    07-07 12:05:41.539: W/ResourceType(26215): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
    07-07 12:05:41.559: W/ResourceType(26215): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
    07-07 12:05:41.669: D/libEGL(26215): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
    07-07 12:05:41.690: D/libEGL(26215): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
    07-07 12:05:41.690: D/libEGL(26215): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
    07-07 12:05:41.720: D/OpenGLRenderer(26215): Enabling debug mode 0
    07-07 12:05:41.770: D/dalvikvm(26215): GC_CONCURRENT freed 126K, 10% free 9710K/10695K, paused 13ms+3ms, total 32ms
    07-07 12:06:00.620: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26215): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
    07-07 12:06:00.620: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(26215): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

please help me...

Comment: do like this ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, imageView); // Default options will be used

Comment: Check my ans : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651291/image-from-url-in-android/19651443#19651443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Universal Image Loader to display image, check if you correctly done given steps below. If not, steps below will also provide basic tutorial for you to use it:

-Create a class that extends application, and put the code below in it. In this case, i named my class UILApp:

```
package com.example.myproject;

import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import android.app.Application;

public class UILApp extends Application{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration configuration = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(configuration);

}

}
```

-Second, in your AndroidManifest.xml file, set name value in your application tag to this class. Example:

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.myproject.UILApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

-Third, cretate your ImageLoader object like this:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .build();

ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
```

On above piece of code, i put on cacheing on disk true. DisplayImageOptions has many other settings you can check out and set. I've created my loader object as a class variable, so i can use it anywhere in the class. For more information visit Universal Image Loader's page on GitHub : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Hope this helps !