# TextView in Universal Image Loader gallery

Tags: android, image, textview, loader, universal

How can I use a textview type in image gallery?

What I do is this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View view = convertView;
   final ViewHolder holder;
   if (convertView == null) {
       view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fotos, parent, false);
       holder = new ViewHolder();
       holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pie);
       holder.image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.miimagen);
       //imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_gallery_image, parent,               false);
       view.setTag(holder);
   } else {
       holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
   }

   holder.text.setText(imageUrls[position]);
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], holder.image, options);

   return view;
}
```

When I call imageLoader the log says View must not be null. If I delete this line the app works and shows me my default image in the fotos.xml

My fotos.xml has a imageview and textview.

Anyone knows what´s wrong here?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: holder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pie);
       holder.image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.miimagen); you need to use view.findViewByID

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651291/image-from-url-in-android/19651443#19651443

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. I didn't put view before my ImageView whean I define it.

This is the correct code:
holder.image=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.image);

it´s works.